# Clarity needed on SVM concepts

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I've been reading up on articles and forums to understand how soft margin affects the classification of new data points, but I still couldn't connect the dots on how soft margin affects the outcome of the classification problem.

Several questions might help me to understand better if someone could assist. I will use the following image as my example.

[image]

1. Does a hard margin mean that no data point can fall within the margin?
2. What is the role of a soft margin? To decide on the influence of each data point against the decision boundary? Aka making misclassified data points less influential against the decision boundary so that these misclassified points can't act as a support vector.
3. Even with a soft margin, the only factor that influences the classification of new data points is still the decision boundary ain't it? E.g., I added an orange and purple point on the image to the right. Orange will still ended up being classified as "Red" while purple as "Blue". Thus, does it mean that a soft margin will not affect the classification of new data points but only for the sake of building the model?

Comment: We do not take pure ML questions here, there are other appropriate places like Stats SE or AI SE.

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

Soft margin is a training time relaxation. Instead of forbidding (mis)classifications within the margin (i.e., making the margin "hard"), a soft margin allows a certain number of (mis)classifications within the margin of the decision boundary. Again, the margin is only a training time consideration, but the resulting decision boundary may be better by fitting the boundary with the softness factor.